# Above show if there is success in Update

Tags: c#

this is how I'm sitting in a problem as do it to find out if it is true or false,

it is true, the move into the content but is false then it just stop now.

That it should be able to do is to show text and simultaneously refresh the page to the user can not just throw content into again. and displaying the content is all true.

**UploadSuccesBesked.cs**

```
    public class UploadSuccesBesked
{

    public class validationResponse
    {
        public string TrueIndhold { get; set; }
        public string Tekst { get; set; }
    }

    public static validationResponse UploadIndhold(string TrueIndhold)
    {

        validationResponse UploadIndhold = new validationResponse();

        int load = 3;
        if (TrueIndhold == "succes")
        {
            UploadIndhold.Tekst = "<div class='alert alert-success'><strong>Succes - Jubbiii!!!</strong> Der kom ingen fejl.!</div>";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("REFRESH", load + ";URL=?opdater=true");
            return UploadIndhold;
        }
        else if (TrueIndhold == "error")
        {
            UploadIndhold.Tekst = "<div class='alert alert-danger'><strong>Fejl!!</strong> Der er sket en fejl, Kontakt os hvis det sker igen!</div>";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("REFRESH", load + ";URL=?opdater=false");
            return UploadIndhold;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**eidtpassword.aspx.cs**

```
if (UploadSuccesBesked.UploadIndhold("succes"))
        {
            PanelIndhold.Visible = true;
            LiteralBesked.Text = /*Tekst come here*/;
        }
```

Error message:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'UploadSuccesBesked.validationResponse' to 'bool'

the reason I have just written the text to come here, for example in success, the text is in Danish now become listed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the signature of your method:

```
public static validationResponse UploadIndhold(string TrueIndhold)
//            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

And that underlined part is your return type. So your method returns an object of that type (or null).

In your check, you do this:

```
if (UploadSuccesBesked.UploadIndhold("succes"))
```

This tries to convert the return value of the method (which is a `validationResponse` object as per above) to a bool, because if statements expect a boolean value as the condition. This of course does not work.

What you should do instead is check whether return value is `null`. And if you save the return value, you can also reuse the text:

```
validationResponse result = UploadSuccesBesked.UploadIndhold("succes");
if (result != null)
{
    PanelIndhold.Visible = true;
    LiteralBesked.Text = result.Tekst;
}
```

Comment: Was it really just what was needed to :). You should thank you for your help !. :) I hope you give a +1 at my question :) Good day!